# colorControlActivated for TextInputLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, material-components

This is my main style for the application

```
<style name="Theme.RoundRobin" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorControlActivated</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">false</item>
</style>
```

as far as I know colorControlHighlight should color the underline , the label and the cursor in the textinputlayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username_til"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Subtitle1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/password_til"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:hint="Username"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/usernameEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Body2"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

None of the colorControls are supposedly working with the new MaterialCompoents.

Am i missing something here

I gave my TextInput this style , yet it appears as if MaterialComponents is not working well with colorControlsX

```
<style name="Widget.RoundRobin.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Caption</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dp</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorSecondaryVariant</item> // this doesn't work too
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/FilledBoxColor"
        ...>
```

with a custom style:

```
  <style name="FilledBoxColor" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- underline color in FilledBox style, border color in OutlinedBox
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color</item>

    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/....</item>
    <!-- The color of the label in all other text field states (such as resting and disabled) -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

The default selector for the `boxStrokeColor` is:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <!-- 4% overlay over 42% colorOnSurface -->
  <item android:alpha="0.46" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.42" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

[image]