# Underline, cursor and hint disappeared at TextInputEditText in TextInputLayout on focus

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android, android-textinputedittext

I have an edit profile screen with bunch of TextInputEditTexts. It worked fine before, but now on focus underline, cursor and hint become invisible.

Has anyone faced the same problem?

[image]

```
...

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/tilFirstName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivContactIcon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/gEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_32"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_24"
        android:hint="@string/profile_edit_hint_first_name"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etFirstName"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/FontRoboRegularSizeMFontPrimaryOneLineMatchWrap"
            tools:text="Oleh"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:nextFocusForward="@id/etLastName"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

...
```

**UPDATE:**
After changing background of the root element it's clear that these elements become white. not disappeared.

[image]

Comment: What is style="@style/FontRoboRegularSizeMFontPrimaryOneLineMatchWrap" ?

Comment: <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_m</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/new_font_primary_color</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">@string/font_roboto_regular</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I just changed background and found out that hint, cursor and underline just become white.

Comment: Quite strange. What are the differences with the other textinputlayout in the screen?

Comment: how did you change the background? I don't see it the component

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, the only difference is that first on in the focus.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200226/discussion-between-oleh-liskovych-and-gabriele-mariotti).

Comment: Ok.Check the colorOnSurface

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742148/colorcontrolactivated-for-textinputlayout-doesnt-work). It explain how the label and underline colors works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default style used by the `TextInputLayout` is

```
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox" parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout">
    <!-- underline color in FilledBox style -->
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/mtrl_filled_stroke_color</item>

    <!-- The color of the label when it is collapsed and the text field is active -->
    <item name="hintTextColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    ....
</style>
```

The `mtrl_filled_stroke_color` is based on the `colorOnSurface`.

Check in your theme the `colorPrimary` and the `colorOnSurface` values, or use a custom style with the same attributes described above.

Comment: This requires switching from AppCompat Theme to Theme.MaterialComponents. Is there any way to fix appearance without switching?

Comment: Quite strange your comment. You are using the component `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText` provided by the Material Components Library. It **requires** a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme).

Comment: My theme is successor of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: You can check the doc. With the version 1.1.0 [it will not be possible](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/internal/ThemeEnforcement.java). In any case, the component uses the style described in the answer. You can try to force another style but it can work in a bad way.

Comment: If I don't switch to MaterialComponents theme and try to use your style, I get:      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant). But if I don't use it, I can open this screen and nothing happens.

Comment: @OlehLiskovych It depends also by the version you are using. In any case you can't use this style without a Material Theme in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're struggling like I did and the above solutions didn't work, it may be that your project's theme was set up with a white colorPrimary.

To fix you could create a custom style for your TextEdits and apply it to each:

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppThemeCorrectPrimaryColor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/notAWhiteColor</item>
</style>
```

EditText:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:theme="@style/AppThemeCorrectPrimaryColor"
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the style for the `TextInputLayout` and define the `colorControlActivated` like

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/greyLight</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/orange</item>
    </style>
```

and use theming instead of styling on the `TextInputLayout`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:theme="@style/Widget.AppTheme.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```